# Trying to call placeOrders function for betfair api

Tags: c#, vb.net, betfair

Trying to invoke placeOrders function from VB.NET code.
I already converted C# Library on betfair website to VB.NET.

Now on the line of calling the method it returns error and the e.data is nothing.

[image]
[image]

```vb
Friend Shared Sub testBetting()
            Try
                Dim placeInstructions As IList(Of PlaceInstruction) = New List(Of PlaceInstruction)()
                Dim placeInstruction = New PlaceInstruction()

                'get the first runner from the market
                Dim runner = marketBook(0).Runners(0)
                Dim selectionId = runner.SelectionId

                placeInstruction.Handicap = 0
                placeInstruction.Side = Side.BACK
                placeInstruction.OrderType = OrderType.LIMIT

                Dim limitOrder = New LimitOrder()
                limitOrder.PersistenceType = PersistenceType.LAPSE
                ' place a back bet at rediculous odds so it doesn't get matched 
                limitOrder.Price = 3.5
                limitOrder.Size = 0.05
                ' placing a bet below minimum stake, expecting a error in report
                placeInstruction.LimitOrder = limitOrder
                placeInstruction.SelectionId = selectionId
                placeInstructions.Add(placeInstruction)

                Dim customerRef = "785895438098" '"9876785895438098726178907895434" '"123456"
                Dim placeExecutionReport = client.placeOrders(marketID, customerRef, placeInstructions)
            Catch apiExcepion As BetfairLib.APINGException
                MessageBox.Show("Got an exception from Api-NG: " + apiExcepion.ErrorCode)
            End Try
        End Sub
```

Comment: The last line before Catch is malformed, and I don't see where marketID is defined.

Comment: @MrGadget you are correct, but same when it is not exists (the comma at the end)

Comment: Are you sure data is nothing, or the named property?
Swap lines 198 and 199...does it still stop on the first of the two?
Add a Watch on ex and data and see what those show.

Comment: @MrGadget those 2 lines can't be swapd as exceptionName variable is declared in first line,

Comment: @MrGadget but running ?data in immediate windows shows >>> Nothing

Comment: It could be that the client lib is hosing the exception either in deserialisation or in reconstructing it from the server response. You could try to install .Net Reflector and see if you can step into the client lib compiled code. It might give you a hint as to what is going on.